# Set chart series name with a variable on a Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to set the series data of a Excel chart through a VB macro with a variable that is actually pointing to the header of a column. Right now the line of code that I have is something like this:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Number of calls (#)").Values
```

I want to change the string "Number of calls (#)" with the variable but it is not working very well. Can someone help me with the syntax for this line of code with a variable?

Comment: Please post the complete code

Comment: Why not just have a template with the chart already set up to bring in the data and title, series names etc then just use the vba to paste the data into place...

Comment: In case you just want to change the series name, you can try:     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Number of calls (#)").Name = "new_name" (or variable)